# How to add multiple values in one attribute in a model in MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model

I am pretty new to MVC and SQL management, and i have this task where i need multiple values in an attribute (if that makes sense)

Currently I have this Cookie model, and an Ingridient model. A cookie is made out of multiple Ingridients. In a list I want to show the name for the cookie, while also showing the ingridients for the cookie.

This is the Cookie model:

```
public class Cookie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Ingredient> Ingridients { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

This is the Ingridient model:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I thought it would work to have an Ingridients list attribute in the Cookie model. But I can't set a list like that in the database. There is only possible to set Id, Name, and DateTime for the cookie, in the database table when i migrate the solution. How can I set multiple ingridients for a cookie?

Comment: You can create a table Ingredient in your database

Comment: When migrating the application adds an Ingridient table in the database. I need a way to "connect" cookies and ingridients.

Comment: You're not showing your modelbuilder code but if your list of ingredients is not populating in Cookie then you're probably not setting up your relationships correctly. See this: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration.

Comment: You also need a Cookie object inside of Ingredient class.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I have this Cookie model, and an Ingridient model. A cookie
> is made out of multiple Ingridients. In a list I want to show the name
> for the cookie, while also showing the ingridients for the cookie.

Seems you are trying to illustrate a list type of your Cookie model which would contain a list of Ingredient those are required to made each perticular Cookie.

Let's assume a cookie name Pine Apple which requires pine apple pulp, pine apple juice and suger as an Ingredient. Thus you want to display that cookie name along with the list of Ingredients together as following:

[image]

> I thought it would work to have an Ingridients list attribute in the
> Cookie model. But I can't set a list like that in the database.

No, entity framework wouldn't generate that automatically, you have to define [entity relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) within your class. Thefore, your existing class need to modify.

> How can I set multiple ingridients for a cookie?

Let's have a look in action how your rquirement can be implemented:

Model:

```
public class Cookie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<Ingredient> Ingridients { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string IngredientName { get; set; }

        public int CookieId { get; set; }

    }
```

Datebase Design:

[image]

[image]

Sample Cookie & Ingredient:

[image]

Db Context Class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
     

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
           
        }
       
        public DbSet<Cookie> Cookies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
     


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Cookie>().ToTable("Cookie");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>().ToTable("Ingredient");

        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           
            var cokie = _context.Cookies.ToList();
            var intgre = _context.Ingredients.ToList();

            var ingridientsDetails = (from cok in cokie
                                  join ing in intgre on cok.Id equals ing.CookieId
                                  select new Cookie
                                  {
                                      Id = cok.Id,
                                      Name = cok.Name,
                                      Ingridients = (intgre.Where(cid => cid.CookieId == cok.Id).ToList()),
                                  }).DistinctBy(id => id.Id).ToList();



            return View(ingridientsDetails);

        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProjctName.Models.Cookie>


<table class="table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id
            <th>Name
            <th>Ingredient Details

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name

                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var ingredient in item.Ingridients)
                    {
                     
                        @ingredient.IngredientName
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>


            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** More details can be found on our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions)